# Zoomcharts API on safari

Tags: canvas, safari, zoomcharts

I am using zoomcharts api for drill downs in pie charts and it seems to work pretty good on all browsers except for safari which crashes after few clicks. I am using basic configurations for it as followed:

```
var data = {
    "subvalues":[
    {"value":50, "name":"Apples", "subvalues":[
        {"value":25, "name":"Red apples"},
        {"value":15, "name":"Yellow apples"},
        {"value":10, "name":"Green apples"}]},
    {"value":30, "name":"Oranges", "subvalues":[
        {"value":10, "name":"Big oranges"},
        {"value":9, "name":"Small oranges"},
        {"value":7, "name":"Green oranges"},
        {"value":4, "name":"Pink oranges"}]},
    {"value":20, "name":"Grapes", "subvalues":[
        {"value":15, "name":"Sweet grapes"},
        {"value":5, "name":"Sour grapes"}]},
    {"value":50, "name":"Other fruits", style:{fillColor:"lightGray"}}]
};

var t = new PieChart({
    container: document.getElementById("demo"),
    area: { height: 350 },
    data: { preloaded: data }
});
```

any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can't reproduce such crash on Safari with these basic settings. ZoomCharts 1.8.0 has been released. Please verify if problem persists.

Also check if you experience the same crash in our site with these settings: https://zoomcharts.com/developers/en/pie-chart/examples/data-sources/preloaded.html

If you only experience crash on your site, then please submit additional information like some other libraries that you are using in your website.